# circular connector identification?

Tags: connector, identification

This connector is part of a home built current controller I found. It is 20 years old. I know it's a long shot, but I am wondering if anyone can identify it, as I would like to use it. The only markings I can see on it are one the back side, it says "CXA" then it enumerates the pins 1 to 6. The outer diameter of the barrel appears to be about 0.7 inches.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's certainly an odd one; I can't seem to find anything even close to it. The pin spacing is very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [this](http://www.switchcraft.com/Category.aspx?Parent=815) type of circular connector.

"EN3® Sealed Connectors, 0.715" OD, 2-18 Contacts"

[image]

There's a similar series mini-CON-X [here](http://www.switchcraft.com/Documents/conxall_catalog.pdf) (page 10) which may be right, but the data is a bit sketchy.

Comment: Looks quite similar except the linked six pin version has a pin in the middle, unlike my connector. It's perhaps a start though.